# Trying to improve efficiency of MVC3 + Unity project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, domain-driven-design, unity-container

I have an MVC3 project that uses Unity for dependency injection.

There is a main MVC3 project, a “domain” class library that sits between MVC3 and the data tier, and a bunch of class libraries that make up the data tier.

(MVC3) – (domain) – (data tier)

This is an example of one of the service constructors in the domain class:

```
public DomainModelCacheServices(
    Data.Interface.ICountryRepository countryRepository,
    Data.Interface.ILanguageRepository languageRepository,
    Data.Interface.ISocialNetRepository socialNetRepository
)
```

Every time a controller is called that has DomainModelCacheServices in its constructor, a new DomainModelCacheServices object is constructed, plus the three repository classes in the constructor of DomainModelCacheServices.

I cannot believe this is efficient!

What makes this worse is that the class DomainModelCacheServices is a cache class.  It loads lists of data that never change, and holds them as statics.  But it still needs to construct three repository classes for every reference!

If I give DomainModelCacheServices the lifetime of a singleton (forever), I have to ensure it is thread-safe, and if the day comes when I am getting hundreds of hits, there’s going to be a lot of locking.

I could change the constructor to this:

```
    public DomainModelCacheServices(
        IServiceLocator serviceLocator
    )
```

I don’t know why, but this doesn’t look right.  The constructor becomes meaningless to the eye, and I have to reference Unity in the domain class and somehow make the domain class aware of the ServiceLocator owned by the MVC3 application.  Maybe the loose-coupling can be too loose?

Maybe constructing all these classes is not as inefficient as it looks I shouldn’t worry about it?

What would be nice is if Unity supported “Lazy” constructor parameters.  But it doesn’t.

So, any ideas on how to make an MVC3 + Unity project more efficient, specifically in the domain model design?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: "If I give DomainModelCacheServices the lifetime of a singleton (forever), I have to ensure it is thread-safe" Don´t you have to that already if it´s static, or I´m I missing something there?

Comment: @Glenn: The fields are static, not the class itself.

Comment: What do you use DomainModelCacheServices for in the first place ? With such a generic name and those constructor parameters, I suspect it tries to do too many things at a time.

Answer (score 1):

The cache shouldn't be definied on the domain level but on the repositories implemntation level (so in DAL). So for example `ICountryRepository` should have two implementations in DAL : **CountryRepository** and **ChachedCountryRepository**. These should be ***wired as decorators*** in Unity (`CountryRepository` is inside the `ChachedCountryRepository`).  `CachedCountryRepository` would check if the data is in the cache and if not it would pass the call to the inner `CountryRepository`.

Creating objects is not expensive and wouldn't care too much about issues as a caching is correctly definied.

Comment: "I personally don't like injecting anything inside my entities" - but DomainModelCacheServices is a service, not an entity, right ? And nothing tells us the kind of cache DomainModelCacheServices deals with is related to the DAL. It could be some other kind of cache.

Comment: Yes in regards to domain service, I've read to fast through the question. I removed this part in the answer. As for "Cache" it has nothing to do in the domain, regardless it's underlying implementation. Cache it's a leaky abstraction of the infrastructure to your domain.

Comment: Agreed. Except if DomainModelCacheServices is in the application layer rather than domain layer. In any case, I'd be curious to know what that service is really used for :)

Comment: The DomainModelCacheServices class is in the domain.  It provides lists of domain models that do not changed.  Fo example, time zone, language names, countries.  When a list is requested from the MVC, it loads data models from the data tier, processes them into domain models, and holds on to them for the rest of the life of the application to save having to load them again.

Answer (score 0):

Great reasoning.

However, creating objects is cheap. I would not create a singleton since you already are caching all objects in static fields. The current approach is easy to understand.

I got another question for you:

Why are you not caching in your repository classes?

The repositories  are responsible for the data and all data handling should be transparent to everything else. It also makes everything easier since they are responsible of updating the data sources. How do you keep the cache in sync with changes today? Through domain events?

I would create a cache class which I would use as a private field in the repository.

Comment: Thanks for the replies!  The reason I am caching at domain level is that the data has already had some business logic applied to it, so the objects I am caching are not data-models, but domain-models.
As an example (I am not actually doing this) countries: 
**Data Model members: CountryId, LongName, Code** and 
**Domain Model members: CountryId, LongName, TruncatedLongName**
If I cached at data-model level I would have to perform the truncation for every call from the domain level to the data-tier.

Comment: DDD repositories should create domain models, not data models.